# Can we hide the sending email address for a Docusign envelope when using the SendOnBehalfOf feature?

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the Docusign API to send out envelopes and we are using the SendOnBehalfOf feature. We have an account with Docusign that is a general mailbox account, like generalmail@xyz.com. With the SendOnBehalfOf (SOBO), we have an actual person's email address on the envelope so that if the recipient has a question, the reply to goes to a real person and not a general mailbox. The business unit does not want the general mailbox account email address to show in the email message sent to the signers. Is it possible, maybe thru modifying the email resource, to plain hide that general mailbox email address?

Answer (score 1):

Kathy,
First off, SOBO is an old/legacy feature. While it's not going away anytime soon, I wouldn't recommend using it. I would encourage you to look into JWT authentication and how you can get what you need done without using SOBO. That would also solve your other issue.

Second, SOBO shouldn't show the email of the system account (the one use for API requests) but the email of the user you are sending on behalf of, hence SOBO. IF that's not what you're seeing - something is wrong. There are many things that can be wrong. I would have to see the code and/or logs to try to figure this out.

Comment: Inbar - I did not know that SOBO was a legacy feature. In our conversations with Docusign, they did not mention it and in fact they recommended using it for what we needed to accomplish. Maybe at some later date we will have to revisit this.